# How to convert char string into hex value

Tags: c

I have one situation where i am receiving characters serially, byte by byte in USB Tx mode. 
Now I'm stuck at where I am receiving `7` and `a` and my objective is to create `0x7a` data.

Please provide me some workaround.

```
void converttohex(int recsize) {

    BYTE ccount = 0;
    //BYTE *recptr = (BYTE*)calloc(CommOP_Rx.bDataLength, sizeof(BYTE));
    *recptr = 88;
    *(recptr + 1) = 16;
    *(recptr + 2) = 1;
    *(recptr + 3) = 224;
    *(recptr + 4) = 1;

    for (xp = 12, s = 5; xp < (CommOP_Rx.bDataLength - 4); xp++,s++) {
        if (xp == 12) {
            for (xp = 12; (*(recimage + xp)) != ','; xp++)
                ccount++;
            if (ccount == 1) {
                xp = 12;
                xq = (*(recimage + xp) - 48);
                *(recptr+s) = xq;
                xp++;
            } else
            if (ccount == 2) {
                xp = 12;
                xq = (*(recimage + xp) - 48) * 10;
                xw = (*(recimage + (++xp)) - 48);
                *(recptr + s) = xq + xw;
                xp++;
            } else
            if (ccount == 3) {
                xp = 12;
                xq = (*(recimage + xp) - 48) * 100;
                xw = (*(recimage + (++xp)) - 48) * 10;
                xe = (*(recimage + (++xp)) - 48);
                *(recptr+s) = xq + xw + xe;
                xp++;
            }
        }
        xp++;
        if (((*(recimage + xp)) == 'a') || ((*(recimage + (++xp))) == 'a')) {
            --xp;
            if (((*(recimage + xp)) == 'a')) {
                xq = (*(recimage + xp) - 48) * 10;
            } else
                xq = (*(recimage + xp) - 48);
            xw = 'a';
            *(recptr + s) = xq  +xw;
        }
        xq = (*(recimage + xp) - 48) * 10;
        xw = (*(recimage + (++xp)) - 48);
        *(recptr + s) = xq + xw;
    }
    for (xp = 0; xp < (CommOP_Rx.bDataLength - 4); xp++) {
        *(recimage + xp)  = *(recptr + xp);
    }
```

Basically here i am sampling some data, which is the array of image in hex, and storing it in my MCU array. But here i have implemented that when i will receive a two consecutive data in which which is an Integer 0-9, then i am subtracting 48 into it as all the bytes are in character encoding, upto this it is working fine, but after receiving A-F of hex, lets suppose i have received '7' & 'a' and it has to be value=0x7a , thus i need this conversion help!!

Comment: and the code with your try...???

Comment: Just shift the bits and combine

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: That code is poorly formatted (in other words: difficult to read) and it looks overly complicated.

Comment: @Sathiya can you please elaborate??

Comment: Sidenote: Instead of using ugly pointer syntax, use cleaner array syntax: `*(recptr + 1) = 16;` -> `recptr[1] = 16;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it in a null-terminated string and read from it.

```
// Assume N is a big number
char str[N] = "7A";
int ret;
sscanf(str, "%x", &ret);
printf("%d", ret); // Output: 122
```

To do it repetitively, let the program construct this array:

```
int i = 0;
while (read_data(&ch)){
    // Assume ch is in "0123456789ABCDEFabcdef"
    str[i++] = ch;
}
str[i] = 0;
// Now parse it
int ret;
sscanf(str, "%x", &ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems quite complicated for me to understand. Just giving a glimpse of what can be done to get hexadecimal value based on your question and not based on your code. Sorry for that.

If you process the two inputs as string then the below approach will suite.

```
char num1[] = "7";
char num2[] = "a";
char num[10];
strcpy (num, num1);
strcat (num, num2);
```

Now `num` has 7a as hexadecimal string

If you have the two inputs as integers then this logic will work

```
int num1,num2,num3;
num1=0x7;
num2=0xa;
num3=(num1<<4)|(num2);
sprintf(str,"0x%x",num3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the hex digits in an array of `char`, null terminate this array an use `sscanf()` or `strtol()` to convert the string to a number.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
char arr[3]={7,10,'\0'};
int arry=0;
scanf(arr, "%x", &arry);
printf("arry = %d\n",arry);
    return 0;
}   
I have tried this, but not working.

Comment: @SaurabhMishra: your code is incorrect: the array should contain characters: `#include <stdio.h> int main() { char arr[3]={'7','a','\0'}; int arry=0; scanf(arr, "%x", &arry); printf("arry = %d\n",arry); return 0; }`